# Array format for vector in Rstan

Tags: arrays, vector, stan

Please create a stan file, for example  aaa.stan  .
And in this aaa.stan file, please write as follows:

```
transformed parameters { 
        vector  [11] xxx [21];
      xxx[33][4]=2;
}
```

when I push the Check button, I encountered the following odd output

```
> rstan:::rstudio_stanc("aaa.stan")
aaa.stan is syntactically correct.
```

Even though, my code is no correct, why does computer say correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That just means that the Stan file parses to a C++ file. But the parser does not check whether things stay within the bounds of the indices, in part because you could declare `vector[K] x;` and it does not know until runtime how large `K` is. In general, the Stan parser has almost no checking of logic, although in this case you will get a runtime error when you assign `2` to `xxx[33][4]`.

Comment: I really appreciate for letting me know about parser of Stan. I also want to confirm me. If I write  ```transformed parameters {
       vector  [10] xxx [2];
      xxx[1,10]=8;
 
}
```
, then parser says that ```aaa.stan is syntactically correct.
```How I can designate vector array? Suppose that we write ```vector  [D] xxx [N]```. Then for all ```d,n ``` such that  ```d ```  and ```n  ``` are not greater than ```D,N,  ```  , the form  ```xxx[n][d] ``` is correct?